# How to use weights to arrange Gridview Items programmatically with TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-tablelayout

I am working on a Suduko solver app. I want the layout to have 9x9 TextView in 9 Gridviews. I want to put below them two buttons (Solve, clear). I have made it but it does not work probably with small devices (Can`t see the buttons and the Grid view turned to scrollable that does not fit the screen)

Here is how I add Textviews to the Gridview

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
String[] arrayEmpty = new String[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
ArrayList<String> listEmpty = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayEmpty));
gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,list));
```

Here is my Layout.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView3"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>
```

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView4"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView6"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>
```

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView7"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView8"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView9"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>
```

```
<TableRow android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/solve_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/solve" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/_clear" />
</TableRow>
```

And this is a screenshot of what I had [image]

But this is what I need my Layout to be with all Devices. Maybe I should use weights, but I don`t know how

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick: For a completely uniform table or grid, you don't need TableView or GridView at all.  Just put everything inside LinearLayout with size=0 and layoutWeight=1. That size=0 seems counter-intuitive, but combined with the layoutWeight=1, it has the effect of giving all child widgets the exact same size, regardless of their contents.

So do something like this:

```xml
<!-- Outer container; a vertical layout that fills the screen -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <!-- first row -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- contents of the first row -->
    <!-- first item in first row -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!-- second item in first row -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!-- third item in first row -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- second row -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- contents of the second row. -->
    <!-- etc -->
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- third row -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- contents of the third row -->
    <!-- etc -->
  </LinearLayout>
  <Button android:id="@+id/solveButton"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/clearButton"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note: I've left it as an exercise for the student to figure out how to put in margins where you want them.

Comment: Ok, but how should I add the TextView to every View from the .java File (Progammatically)?

Comment: LinearLayout does not handle caching and if you put too many views inside it enough to run out of memory, the app will crash. But in gridview or listview, that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

Check this Sudoku project -

[Git Hub](https://github.com/romario333/opensudoku/tree/master/OpenSudoku)

Also

[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409099/building-a-gui-for-a-sudoku-solver-complete-with-ascii-example)

Here you can find layout and source code for Sudoku and also other useful things.