# XML GUI Toolkit for java swing

Tags: java, swing

Now I want to create a stand-alone application using java. In my earlier projects, I only used netbeans default gui builder and in eclipse it replaces visual editor. But during the search with google I touched through the area which covers the GUI building with XML. I want to understood which is the best way to keep our application IDE independant.

So anyone can suggest which is the best XML UI toolkit in both netbeans and eclipse? 
 and why they remains so?.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This opinion might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126779/building-a-gui-in-java/1127151#1127151

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to answer as-is.

Java GUIs are primarily Swing GUIs.

"XML" is a generic data format technology that can be used for many, many different things - including declarative UIs.  Microsoft's "[XAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx)L" is one example of such an XML-based UI.

Answer (score 0):

There is one library called SwiXML(http://www.swixml.org/), but havent used it much, I would prefer using http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/looks/index.html or http://swingx.java.net/ for devlopment of UI.

Answer (score 0):

FXML in JavaFX: XML-based UI framework in JavaFX...Too bad, it is not really based on Java Swing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm

http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/10/oracle-pushes-its-idea-of-java.php

http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/11/27/javafx-has-fxml-as-flexible-xml/

So, the closest you can get is with a shareware [SpeedJG](http://www.wsoftware.de/SpeedJG/) - a Java Swing GUI Builder IDE that uses a XML file as the UI template. For example:

```
import speed.util.*;

public class MyJFrame2 extends MyJFrameController
{ public MyJFrame2() throws Exception
  { super(SpeedJG.CreateGUI(XMLDocument.fromFile("MyJFrame.xml").getContent()));
    myJFrame.show();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  { MyJFrame2 myJFrame = new MyJFrame2();
  }
}
```

This is taken from http://www.wsoftware.de/SpeedJG/HowTos.html